# How to compare/find a list of XMLGregorianCalendar dates

Tags: java, xml, datetime-comparison, xmlgregoriancalendar

For eg:
we have a `List<XMLGregorianCalendar> dates` we need to find the latest date in this list.

Really appreciate your help!

Comment: `dates.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Function.identity())).get();` use `min` function for older date.

Comment: Alternatively, dates and calendars are comparable objects, you could put them in a SortedSet instead of a list and then get the first or the last. See `NavigableSet.pollFirst` or `NavigableSet.pollLast`. TreeSet implements NavigableSet.

Comment: XMLGregorianCalendar does not implement Comparable.

Comment: Do your `XMLGregorianCalendar` objects represent dates without time of day, or have they got time and/or UTC offset (called timezone in the API doc)?

Answer (score 2):

Rather strangely, `XMLGregorianCalendar` has a `compareTo()` method but does not implement `Comparable`, which makes this unnecessarily difficult. I'd be inclined to convert your values to something more Java-friendly like a `ZonedDateTime` and work with that. I guess if you're using XMLGregorianCalendar then it's probably because you're using JAXB data binding to XML: the class was invented because at the time, none of the Java date/time options quite matched the XSD data types, but that's no longer really the case.

Comment: The method is called `compare` and should not be confused with a usual `compareTo` method. `compare()` may return `LESSER`, `EQUAL`, `GREATER` or `INDETERMINATE`.

Comment: *For example, there is no determinate ordering between (a) 2000-01-20T12:00:00 and (b) 2000-01-20T12:00:00Z. Based on timezones currently in use, (c) could vary from 2000-01-20T12:00:00+12:00 to 2000-01-20T12:00:00-13:00. It is, however, possible for this range to expand or contract in the future, based on local laws. Because of this, the following definition uses a somewhat broader range of indeterminate values: +14:00..-14:00.* (from [XML doc](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime-order)).

Comment: Yes, thanks. In practice in a given dataset the values usually either all have a timezone or all have none, which is why it's best to convert to a data type such as ZonedDateTime that makes ordering more predictable.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Kay said in a comment, in practice date-times in a list usually all have time of day or none of them, and all have UTC offset (“timezone” in the XML parlance) or none. And this is a requirement for your request to make sense. Which of `23:34:45` and `2021-03-31` is later? `XMLGregorianCalendar` is flexible enough to accommodate both.

If your `XMLGregorianCalendar` objects all have full dates, times and offset, I suggest sorting them as `OffsetDateTime`s:

```
    DatatypeFactory factory = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
    List<XMLGregorianCalendar> dates = Arrays.asList(
            factory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(
                    2021, DatatypeConstants.MARCH, 30, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0),
            factory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(
                    2021, DatatypeConstants.MARCH, 30, 9, 0, 0, 0, 60),
            factory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(
                    2021, DatatypeConstants.MARCH, 30, 13, 0, 0, 0, 60));
    
    if (dates.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No dates");
    } else {
        XMLGregorianCalendar maxDate
                = Collections.max(dates,
                        Comparator.comparing(xgc -> OffsetDateTime.parse(xgc.toString())));
        System.out.println(maxDate );
    }
```

Output from this snippet is:

> 2021-03-30T13:00:00.000+01:00

I have chosen my data so that the first and the last item in the list denote the same point in time, only one is on UTC, the other at offset +01:00 (for example Irish Summer Time). That the latter is output is no coincidence. `OffsetDateTime.compareTo()` sorts first by point in time (instant in java.time parlance), next by local date-time, and since 13 sounds later than 12, this is chosen.

There are more ways to convert from `XMLGregorianCalendar` to `OffsetDateTime`. I chose parsing as string because it gives us validation that the `XMLGregorianCalendar` has all of date, time and offset.

If *date* is to be taken literally, your objects represent only dates, instead use `LocalDate`. The code is almost the same:

```
    List<XMLGregorianCalendar> dates = Arrays.asList(
            factory.newXMLGregorianCalendarDate(2021, DatatypeConstants.MARCH, 26,
                    DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED),
            factory.newXMLGregorianCalendarDate(2021, DatatypeConstants.MARCH, 29,
                    DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED),
            factory.newXMLGregorianCalendarDate(2021, DatatypeConstants.MARCH, 28,
                    DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED));
    
    if (dates.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No dates");
    } else {
        XMLGregorianCalendar maxDate
                = Collections.max(dates,
                        Comparator.comparing(xgc -> LocalDate.parse(xgc.toString())));
        System.out.println(maxDate );
    }
```

> 2021-03-29

If you have got dates and times but no offsets, use `LocalDateTime` in the same way.